# Mypy ignores types of package, despite `py.typed`

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy, python-poetry

I am maintaining two repositories using `poetry`, let's call them `repo_main` and `repo_dependency`. Both of them use `python 3.8` and have `mypy` (`v0.942`) type hints and, as the names suggest, `repo_main` depends on `repo_dependency`. Now, when I run `mypy` on `repo_main`, the type hints of `repo_dependency` get de-facto ignored and effectively treated as `Any`s. I then tried adding a `py.typed` file into every sub-package of `repo_dependency` with no results, the types are still ignored. The structure of `repo_dependency` looks somewhat like this:

```
repo_dependency/
  - repo_dependency/
    - package1/
      - __init__.py
      - py.typed
      - stuff.py
    - package2/
      - __init__.py
      - py.typed
      - stuff.py
    - __init__.py
    - py.typed
  - other_non_distributed_things/
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. In fact, adding a `py.typed` file causes mypy to no longer recognize any of the functions and variables in the package ('*error: Module has no attribute "..."*').

Comment: I solved the issue with a workaround. I wrote a bash script that creates stubs for all my packages (using mypy's stubgen) and I publish them together with the library. It works as a workaround, but it might not be the most elegant solution.

Comment: So you need stubs in there? Even if the code is already annotated? Why don’t you write an answer? I’m happy to give you the bounty if this gets stuff to work!

Comment: Sure thing! I ended up working on this for a week or so and at the end I totally forgot to post an answer. I will add it asap! :)

Comment: The bounty expires in 24 hours. If you want it, you should post an answer before it expires!

Answer (score 1):

This is, to me, not at all clear from the documentation. Adding a `py.typed` file doesn’t get mypy to look into the package sources for type information. Mypy will only look in stub files for such information (for external packages). Also, putting `.pyi` stub files next to the package sources will not convince mypy to look into those stub files.

So, one needs to add **both** the `py.typed` file **and** the `.pyi` stub files.

To me this seems terribly redundant, which is why it’s so unintuitive that we need both.